# How new Java.util.Date() works while other classes return just reference?

Tags: java, constructor, reference, heap-memory, java.util.date

I am curious as to why `new Java.util.Date()` returns Date object but not address(reference) to itself on heap:

```
System.out.println(new Date()); //Should print address(reference)
```

of object on   heap?

like every other class I've been learning about for example:

```
Cat cat = new Cat();  //new Cat() returns reference which is stored in cat;
```

how can I implement it in my classes?

Comment: Override `toString()`

Comment: Why do you think `new Date()` does not return a reference to a `Date` object on the heap?

Comment: Also note that the [default `toString` inherited from `Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--) does **not** print out the address of the object in the heap. It prints out the object's hash code, which isn't its address.

Comment: I always thought of reference as some form of address like 0x23232, Can a date be reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`java.util.Date`, like a lot of other classes in the JDK, overrides [`toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--), which allows you to control the string representation of your objects.

You can, of course, do this for your own classes too.

Comment: @Override
public String toString() {
  return "meow";
} Works like a charm 10/10 would ask again As to why it works i need to figure it out later :P